# How to set boundary line of small pixel in JHeatChart heat map chart?

Tags: java, jheatchart

I use [`JHeatChart`](http://www.javaheatmap.com) to generate a heat map chart as below; but we can see that if the value is same of neighbor pixel, they will combine to a big pixel because small pixel has not a boundary line. How can I set a boundary line for each pixel, so that they can separate clear when they have same value. And if I want to set several color not gradually color, what should i do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [`JHeatChart`](http://www.javaheatmap.com/), override the `drawHeatMap()` method and specify a different boundary color prior to invoking [`draw()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#draw-java.awt.Shape-), (untested):

```
private void drawHeatMap(Graphics2D chartGraphics, double[][] data) {
    …
    Graphics2D heatMapGraphics = heatMapImage.createGraphics();
    for (int x=0; x<noXCells; x++) {
        for (int y=0; y<noYCells; y++) {
            // Set colour depending on zValues.
            heatMapGraphics.setColor(getCellColour(data[y][x], lowValue, highValue));
            int cellX = x*cellSize.width;
            int cellY = y*cellSize.height;
            heatMapGraphics.fillRect(cellX, cellY, cellSize.width, cellSize.height);
            // Draw boundary 
            Rectangle2D block = new Rectangle2D.Double(
                cellX, cellY, cellSize.width, cellSize.height));
            heatMapGraphics.setPaint(boundaryColor);
            heatMapGraphics.draw(block);
        }
    }
    …
}
```

Comment: sorry, this chart is generated by JheatChart, in JheatChart there is no XYBlockRenderer.

Comment: You may be able to use the same approach.

Comment: Can you give more detailed description? Thank you.

Comment: I've outlined an (untested) approach above.